# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when remove from superview

Tags: uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access, addsubview, superview

My project using ARC, so I can't use retain nor release, in ViewController A, I init ViewController B and add its view as a subview:

```
ViewControllerB *viewB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:viewB.view];
```

And in ViewControllerB, I make a button and when user click on it, the view will removed from superview:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

And the result is EXC_BAD_ACCESS. 
Please help me and sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think viewB is not local variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too..

Try something like this:

```
NSLog("self.view retain count: %d", self.view.retainCount);
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
NSLog("self.view retain count: %d", self.view.retainCount);
```

or:

```
NSLog("self.view.superview retain count: %d", self.view.superview.retainCount);
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
NSLog("self.view.superview retain count: %d", self.view.superview.retainCount);
```

It's not good practice, but maybe you will catch a memory leak error...
If you are using ARC - it doesn't protect you from memory management errors...

I'm sorry for my English if something wrong.